# Stanford CoreNLP using Chinese on Spark error : Unknown language UniversalChinese

Tags: java, maven, stanford-nlp

I'm using Stanford CoreNLP to do POS tagging for Chinese corpus.
Now I want to use it on Spark but I get this error.

```
java.io.IOException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unknown language UniversalChinese
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1163)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.ParallelCollectionPartition.readObject(ParallelCollectionRDD.scala:70)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1058)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1909)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2018)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1942)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:373)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:72)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:98)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:194)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide more details about how you are calling Stanford CoreNLP?

My first guess is that there is a mismatch between the code jar you are using and the model.  What jars are you using for the code and for the models?

If that isn't the issue if you could describe the code you are using some more with some examples I can look into it more.  Are you using the standard Spark set up for Stanford CoreNLP?

This one: https://github.com/databricks/spark-corenlp

Comment: Thanks for your response!
I didn't use spark-nlp, But I think the problem is that I try to use
`List<CoreMap> sentences = annotation.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class);`
combine to JAVARDD using JavaSparkContext.parallelize()

Now I split the sentences myself and it works!